# How to update frequency of WiFi configurations in Android?

Tags: android, wifi, frequency

I want to change the frequency of wifi to get every channel signal strength. I wanted to use Java reflection but can not come out effect. So I want to you for help.

Answer (score 0):

You question isn't clear. Frequency has nothing to do with getting signal strength. Signal strength is calculated by the WiFi client upon receiving of frame. If you want to get every channel signal strength, you need to do WiFi scanning. Scanning is defined in 802.11 (WiFi) protocol and is done every n time units without user intervention.